# Handling ComplexType json in OData for Mule

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule4

I am trying to process an odata.raml for complex type. Here is my request would look like

```
{
"studentNumber": "QA1V2US86940109",
"admissionDate": "2021-04-02T15:44:04Z",
"contactAddress": {
  "addressId": "28067277799447",
  "address1": "123 Windmill Road"
}
```

}

This my odata.raml

```
#%RAML 1.0 Library
uses:
  odata: libraries/odataLibrary.raml

types:
  students:
    (odata.remote): Students
    properties:
      studentNumber:
        type: string
        (odata.key): true
        (odata.nullable): true
      admissionDate:
        type: datetime-only
        (odata.nullable): true
        (odata.key): false
        
      contactAddress:
        type:object
        (odata.nullable): true
        (odata.key): false
        properties:
          addressId:
            type: string
            (odata.nullable): true
            (odata.key): false
          address1:
            type: string
            (odata.nullable): true
            (odata.key): false
```

This is the odata.raml but Mules doesn't take object type. But any idea how to consume this in Mule?

thanks in advance

Comment: "Mules doesn't take object type" what does that mean? Is there an error at some point. Provide symptoms description, error messages. Are you using APIKit? Which version?

Comment: In the given example, we have `contactAddress` as nested object to `students` so Mule OData Apikit parser does not understand this and throws  "Error: Type not supported of property contactAddress". I hope you understand this